# Universal cover of complete hyperbolic surfaces and torsion-free, discrete groups of isometries of $\mathbb{H}^2$

Tags: manifolds, riemann-surfaces, topological-groups, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces

I'm taking a course this semester, and in it we proved that any complete hyperbolic surface is universally covered by $\mathbb{H}^2$. The text, found at http://www.math.brown.edu/~res/Papers/surfacebook.pdf, that we were given for the course, after proving the theorem, discusses only how this result opens the door to many beautiful tilings of the hyperbolic plane.

I asked my professor what the mathematical significance of the result is (I'm still new with the material so I haven't really gotten a hold of the big picture just yet). I can't remember exactly what he said, but it was something along the lines of

*"Because of the result, if we wish to study complete hyperbolic surfaces, we can instead study the quotients $\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a torsion-free, discrete group of isometries of $\mathbb{H}^2$".*

I looked up the Wikipedia article on "Hyperbolic space" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_space, and in it, it is said (under "Hyperbolic manifolds"),

*Every complete, connected, simply-connected manifold of constant negative curvature $−1$ is isometric to the real hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$. As a result, the universal cover of any closed manifold $M$ of constant negative curvature $−1$, which is to say, a hyperbolic manifold, is $\mathbb{H}^n$. Thus, every such $M$ can be written as $\mathbb{H}^n/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is a torsion-free, discrete group of isometries on $\mathbb{H}^n$.*

(I checked Wikipedia to make sure I wasn't remembering incorrectly what my professor told me.)

My question is, how does the fact that the universal cover of any complete hyperbolic surface is $\mathbb{H}^2$ imply that any suchcomplete hyperbolic surface can be written $\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma$?

Comment: It reminds me something like that the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$ of a manifold $M$ acts on its universal cover $H$, such that $H/\pi_1(M) \cong M$, and probably the loops in $\pi_1(M)$ may be represented also by corresponding *isometries*.

Answer (score 5):

If $M$ is a closed, complete hyperbolic manifold, then the hyperbolic structure lifts to its universal cover, $\widetilde{M}$.  This means that $\Gamma = \pi_1(M)$ acts on $\widetilde{M}$ by isometries, and $M = \widetilde{M}/\Gamma$.  Since $\widetilde{M}$ is isometric to $\mathbb{H}^n$, we have $M = \mathbb{H}^n/\Gamma$.  If $\Gamma$ had torsion, then the action would not be fixed-point free and the quotient would have a cone point and not be a manifold, so we can conclude that $\Gamma$ has no torsion.

(Here's a short discussion of bigger picture because it's *interesting!*  Study of hyperbolic surfaces is especially relevant for dimensions $2$ and $3$, where "most" manifolds are hyperbolic.  For orientable closed surfaces, the Euler characteristic and Gauss-Bonnet imply that only $S^2$ and $T^2$ are not hyperbolic.  Geometrization (Thurston-Perelman are the two biggest names here) states that if a closed $3$-manifold $M$ has: $\pi_1M$ infinite (i.e., $M$ is not covered by $S^3$), $\pi_1(M)$ not a free product (i.e., no incompressible spheres - $M$ is prime), and $\pi_1(M)$ contains no $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (i.e., no incompressible tori), then $M$ is hyperbolic.  In three dimensions, once a space is hyperbolic, its geometric invariants become *topological* invariants by Mostow rigidity: If two hyperbolic manifolds are homotopy-equivalent, then that homotopy-equivalence was induced by an isometry.)

Comment: If you would like, I can add more information about why the hyperbolic structure lifts to the universal cover and why the deck transformations are isometries.

Comment: Sorry for the necropost; I would love it if you did add info., and/or refs.